# Xfburn - error diagnostic

Tags: xfce

I want to burn a `mp4` file to CD or DVD using `xfburn version 0.5.4` and ubuntu 16.04.1. After I insert a empty DVD the `xburn` GUI starts automatically and I select "New Data Composition". But the writing ends up with a error message:

> Failure: Burn run failed

I don't know what's going wrong? Are there any log-files?